# Asp.Net Core Identity Get Integer User Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC Core n-tier application. I changed default primary key to integer. There is no problem. But i try to GetUserId() UserManager's default method returns string. Am i write my own method or i did do something wrong?

```
//In controller
public int GetLoggedUserId()
{
    //it's return still string and of course i can't compile my code 
    //problem is here
    return UserService.GetUserId(); 
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string LogoPath { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public MyUserManager(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
                            IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store,
                            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
                            IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher,
                            IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators,
                            IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators,
                            ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
                            IServiceProvider services,
                            ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger) :
        base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher,
            userValidators,
            passwordValidators,
            keyNormalizer,
            errors,
            services,
            logger)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
        .AddUserManager<MyUserManager>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 3):

The user id is stored as a claim on the user principal. You can access it via (in a controller/page/view):

```
string userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

The claim is stored as a string, so if you need an int:

```
var userIdClaim = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
var userId = int.TryParse(userIdClaim, out var id) ? id : 0;
```

The user principal exists on `HttpContext`, so outside of places where the `User` convenience property exists, you'd need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and then:

```
var userIdClaim = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default method `.GetUserId()` does indeed return a string. This problem can be solved by writing a custom method that accesses the int value from the database and returns it to your `GetLoggedUserId()` method.